# ROR syntax error with a for each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i'm trying to display all patients in the database in rails. I'm getting an error expecting keyword do. But do is here.

Any suggestions?

> /home/ubuntu/workspace/shc-pms/app/views/patients/index.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' }, method :delete );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ^

```
<div class="patients">
    <% @patients.each do |patient| %>
        <div class="patient">
            <h3><%= link_to patient.name, patient_path(patient) %></h3>
            <p><%= patient.age %></p>
            <!--<p><%= patient.phone %></p>-->
            <!--<p><%= patient.ailment %></p>-->
            <!--<p><%= patient.appointment %></p>-->
            <!--<p><%= patient.status %></p>-->
            <ul class="patient-action">
                <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_patient_path(patient)  %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Delete", patient_path(patient), data: {
                    confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete: #{patient.name}?",
                }, method :delete  %></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: It might not matter, depending on your version of ruby. But you don't need the comma after the "confirm" message.

Comment: Nope. That didn't fix it

Comment: I think it was Ruby 2 which included the change to ignore that trailing comma. Anyway, I'm confident my answer will solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the hash key `method` is not followed by a colon.

Replace `method :delete` with `method: :delete`.

---

Peripheral issue: That delete call is split across lines in an unusual way. It won't stop ruby from interpreting it, but it does make it harder to read. I'd recommend changing it to this:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to(
        "Delete", 
         patient_path(patient), 
         data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete: #{patient.name}?"}, 
         method: :delete
       ) %>
</li>
```

There are differences of opinion on how to do this, but that's my suggestion.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you